# Meteor update Mongo Sub Collection, not proceeding

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a an array within my object which contains other object and i am trying to selectively update one of those objects based on a value (term) within it. However i am failing miserably, every time i add the update code the function just seems to hand at that call and doesn't proceed through the rest of the function, i can tell as none of the console.log calls after that point get called.

Here is the structure of the object i am fetching:

```
{ "_id" : "KH5SsND7f9urKSEyz", 
"eventName" : "macmillan", 
"twitterEnabled" : true, 
"instagramEnabled" : false, 
"vineEnabled" : false, 
"fetchCount" : 2, 
"enabled" : true, 
"searchTerms" : [ { "term" : "badger", "latestTwitter" : 0, "latestInstagram" : 0, "latestVine" : 0 }, { "term" : "freedom", "latestTwitter" : 0, "latestInstagram" : 0, "latestVine" : 0 } ] 
}
```

I can access and log  this object to the console by calling if eventID is set properly in the function.

```
console.log(HTLEvents.find({_id: eventID}));
```

However when i call this to update the method just stops, no errors, just doesn't proceed.

```
HTLevents.update( {_id : eventID , "searchTerms.term" : searchTerm } , 
{$set : {"searchTerms.$.latestTwitter" : latest} } , 
false , 
true)
```

I have triple checked and all the variables used are not undefined and have correct values.

Here is the complete function, this is called using a Meteor.call from a SyncedCron recurring event

```
Meteor.call('searchTermsUpdateLatest', eventList[eventi]._id, returnValue[i][1].searchedTerm, returnValue[i][1].networkSearched, returnValue[i][1].latestID, function (error, eventList) {function . . . . }
```

As it is being called with a callback it's running Async.

```
HTLEvents = new Mongo.Collection('htlevents');

Meteor.methods({
    fetchEnabledEvents: function() {
        return HTLEvents.find({enabled: true}, {}).fetch();
    },
    searchTermsUpdateLatest: function(eventID, searchTerm, network, latest, callback) {
        console.log('Updating:' + eventID);
        console.log(eventID + " " + searchTerm + " " + network + " " + latest);
        console.log(HTLEvents.find({_id: eventID}));
        console.log(HTLEvents.find({_id: eventID , "searchTerms.term" : searchTerm}));
        var err = undefined
        if (eventID && searchTerm && network && latest) {
            console.log("All parameters set, now updating the " + network + " for " + searchTerm);
            if(network === "twitter"){
                console.log("Updating twitter latest id for " + searchTerm);
                HTLevents.update( {_id : eventID , "searchTerms.term" : searchTerm } , 
                {$set : {"searchTerms.$.latestTwitter" : latest} } , 
                false , 
                true)
            } else if (network == "instagram") {
                console.log("Updating instagram latest id for " + searchTerm);
                HTLevents.update({_id : { _str: eventID } , "searchTerms.term":searchTerm} , {$inc: {"searchTerms.$.latestInstagram": latest}});
            } else if (network == "vine") {
                console.log("Updating vine latest id for " + searchTerm);
                HTLevents.update({_id : { _str: eventID } , "searchTerms.term":searchTerm} , {$inc: {"searchTerms.$.latestVine": latest}});
            }
        } else {
            err = "Unable to update latestID, one or more values not set in method call."
            console.log("Unable to update latestID, one or more values not set in method call.")
        }
        console.log('Updated:')
        console.log(HTLevents.find({_id : eventID}));
        callback();
    },
});
```

I fully expect i'm doing something stupid, so sorry in advance, but i am very new to both Meteor and Javascript.

Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

Unlike normal node.js code, you don't explicitly add a callback to your method signature in meteor. Your method definition should look like:

```
searchTermsUpdateLatest: function(eventID, searchTerm, network, latest) {...}
```

Similarly, you don't invoke the callback at the end of the function (remove the last line). If the method should return a value, you can explicitly do that at the end of your function.

See the documentation for [Meteor.call](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) for more details and examples.

Note that if you are making the call from `SyncedCron`, then it's running on your server and you'll probably want an asynchronous call style (don't pass the callback).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for yo reply, yes this code will only ever run on the server. I guess the callback is unnecessary really as i could do the insert in the method. I have however removed the reference to the callback and even add the following to the very top of the function, and the function just seems to stop at this line and go no further, no error, nothing it just stops. I have even hard coded the values and am only trying to update the main object rather than anything in the sub array.

Comment: HTLevents.update( {_id : 'KH5SsND7f9urKSEyz'} , {$set : {"enabled" : false}});

Comment: Yeah that certainly is weird... I can't think of a good reason for a method just halting in the middle of a DB operation. Is your CPU at 100% or is your hard disk going crazy or anything like that? Maybe just try removing lines of code until you get something to work.

Comment: Ok i'm going to try moving the mongo methods to a separate method that's not using a Meteor.Call within another Meteor.Call that's within an SyncredCron call, just to make things a bit simple and see what happens. Will update back once i've made the changes. If that doesn't help i'm a little stumped.